# MA27 solver HSL installation with Python Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

Is there a way to install MA27 linear solver? Please share a weblink or instructions if possible.
Right now I am running ipopt 3.11.1 and its using mumps as the linear solver and is very slow for my optimization.

What commands need to be run to connect the downloaded HSL files and the existing ipopt?

Alternatively, is there any package (ipopt + ma27) that I can use with Pyomo? I ended up with ipopt 3.11.1 because newer version of ipopt were not running with Pyomo.

Many thanks